# How to move an object along a line given two points?

Tags: c++, line, angle, trigonometry

In my game I'm working on, I have a tower that will shoot at an enemy. I'm trying to get my tower shoot to the enemy when the enemy becomes in range. My fireball shows up, however I'm having problem moving the fireball to the enemy. My latest attempt just makes the ball dance around on the screen.

the ball has an x and y position (which resembles where the ball starts.
The ball also has a newX and newY position in which is where the enemy is. I was thinking about doing the Pythagorean theorm, but that only gets me the length of the line I want to travel in.  Then I was searching online and found out about sin, cos, and atan. I was using atan to get the angle of the slope that I calculated, then plugging the angle in for sin and cos.

My Ball::Update function looks like this:

```
int dx = newX - x;
int dy = newY - y;

int ang = atan(dy, dx);

x += cos(ang);
y += sin(ang);
```

That code there makes the ball appear to 'dance' on the screen. It doesn't move at all. I tested my code with these lines:

x += cos(45);
y += sin(45);

And the ball moves in a 45 degree angle (heading south east) which is expected. So I'm guessing that my error is when calculating the angle. Any math experts that can help?

Comment: `ang` should be a floating point unit and use `atan2`. x and y should also be floating point units if they are not already.

Comment: I really doubt you use e.g. `sin(45)` to calculate the sinus, since [`std::sin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin) (and the other trigonometric functions) expects its argument in *radians*.

Comment: Why that complicated? Please, search for linear interpolation. x(t) = (1 - t) * x0 + t * x1. To go from x0 to x1 iterate t from 0 ... 1 in arbitrary steps. (Apply the same formula for y to compute x and y for t pairwise.)

Comment: Typically the calculations aren't based on angles, but by direction vectors

Comment: `cos(45)` wont give the result you think. The arguments to trigonometric functions are in radians, not in degrees.

Comment: 45rad -> 58 degrees (and a few loops)   which while not far off is not 45 degrees.  Your testing is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is a small sample to demonstrate [**linear interpolation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) for pairs (x, y):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  double x0 = 2.0, y0 = 3.5;
  double x1 = 7.0, y1 = 2.0;
  // do linear interpolation in n steps
  enum { n = 10 };
  for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
    double t = (double)i / n;
    double xT = (1.0 - t) * x0 + t * x1;
    double yT = (1.0 - t) * y0 + t * y1;
    std::cout << i << ":\tt: " << t << ",\tx: " << xT << ",\ty: " << yT << '\n';
  }
  // your code goes here
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0:  t: 0,   x: 2,   y: 3.5
1:  t: 0.1, x: 2.5, y: 3.35
2:  t: 0.2, x: 3,   y: 3.2
3:  t: 0.3, x: 3.5, y: 3.05
4:  t: 0.4, x: 4,   y: 2.9
5:  t: 0.5, x: 4.5, y: 2.75
6:  t: 0.6, x: 5,   y: 2.6
7:  t: 0.7, x: 5.5, y: 2.45
8:  t: 0.8, x: 6,   y: 2.3
9:  t: 0.9, x: 6.5, y: 2.15
10: t: 1,   x: 7,   y: 2
```

[**Life demo on ideone**](https://ideone.com/prLOvM)

Comment: Note that in the context of a game with projectiles, if `t` grows linearly with the time, all projectiles will take the same time to reach their target no matter the distance (which may or may not be desirable). If instead you want the speed to be constant, you can precompute a normalized direction vector `v` and move the projectile by `speed*v` at each step (quick example: https://ideone.com/YNELkN ). The (fairly simple) math behind it is the same though.

Comment: Another solution to make the speed constant is to precompute the expected time `T` for each projectile to reach its target at spawn (and store it somewhere), then have `t` increase by steps of `1/T` (rather than a fixed hardcoded step).

Comment: @Caninonos Good point. To manage this the number of steps should consider the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between (x0, y0) and (x1, y1). Now, we have again Pythagoras (already mentioned by OP). I had another idea: Making t = sin²(Pi * i / n), you had acceleration and deceleration. So, the sample shows the principle and any enhancements may be thought be the OP...

Comment: t = sin²(Pi * i / n) is wrong. Better is t = 0.5 - cos(Pi * i / n) / 2. (Just fiddled a bit in Excel.) The former is related but not right in this sample.